# VB - How to Import non- .system libraries

Tags: vb.net, import, basic

I want to use a third-party library so I typed

```
Option Strict Off
Imports System
Imports NXOpen
Imports System.Diagnostics
```

but after compiling it says "cant find NXOpen Namespace" and so on

Why is that?

PS: NO, I am NOT using VisualStudio, I make everything in Notepad++ and compile via vbs on commandline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a reference to your NxOpen assembly when building:

```
vbc /reference:NxOpen.dll myvbsource.vb
```

(if your assembly is called NxOpen ...)

Comment: Holy Jizz, this simple Information stood NOWHERE but now it works, thank you very much!